# Firebase login stuck on Android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Around 12/27/21 til' now for 4 days, I've noticed that Firebase authentication has been extremely slow on Android only. When I try to login using the auth ui interface, I get stuck on the loading screen for around 5-10 minutes. This happens for both login and sign up.

[image]

Here's the code I used:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            // Choose authentication providers
            List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().setRequireName(false).build()
            );

            // Create and launch sign-in intent
            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                            .build(),
                    1);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            //login
        }
    }
}
```

Things I've tried/noticed:

1. To verify this wasn't just a problem with the auth ui, I also tried calling the Firebase APIs, `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, but I also get the same problem, and the `addOnCompleteListener` isn't triggered until 5-10 minutes later.
2. I've tested this problem on a second Android device and was able to reproduce the same problem.
3. I tried testing the Firebase authentication on iOS devices connected to the same Firebase project, and the authentication works fine. There is no delay.

The Firebase authentication on Android used to work fine for me until recently. What is causing the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Not sure if you got this working but my app is having the same issue. Made a new AVD and it works fine. This may be related to my physical device being unable to receive security or playstore updates (Not sure what the issue is, get an error about updates being temporarily unavailable).